# Visual Studio PowerShell Drag & Drop Attachments From Outlook to List Box

Tags: winforms, powershell, visual-studio-2019

i have got the drag and drop working on my Windows Form. i can drop items from my desktop or any folder but if i try to Drag an attachment straight from Outlook it won't do any thing. do i need to add extra PowerShell commands int my current code

```
######################################## This is For Drag And Drop 

  $listBox1_DragOver = [System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler]{
    if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) 
    {
        $_.Effect = 'Copy'
    }
    Else
    {
        $_.Effect = 'None'
    }
    }

    $listBox1_DragDrop = [System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler]{
        foreach ($filename in $_.Data.GetData([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) 
        {
            $listBox1.Items.Add($filename)
        }

        }

        ### Add events to form ###

    $listBox1.Add_DragOver($listBox1_DragOver)
    $listBox1.Add_DragDrop($listBox1_DragDrop)
    #$form.Add_FormClosed($form_FormClosed)

        #### Show form and return result ###
    $dialogResult = $Form12.ShowDialog()
    if ($dialogResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
     {
      $Form12.SuspendLayout()
       [array]$items =  $listbox1.Items| sort -CaseSensitive
       if ($items.Count -gt 1){
       $items
       }
       ELSE
       {
       [string]$items[0]
       }
      $Form12.Close() | out-null
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lot's of research i came across the code below, to summarise what it does.

it will let you drag and drop files out of Outlook, it will then copy and paste that into a folder which then gives you the path and file name. it is pretty cool so if anyone else is stuck here is my working script and how i implemented it to my form

```
######################################## This is For Drag And Drop 
$Listbox1.AllowDrop = $true 
$Listbox1.Add_DragDrop({
    if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) { 
        foreach ($FileName in $_.Data.GetData([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
            Copy-Item -Path $FileName -Destination $textbox6.text -Force
            $Listbox1.Items.Add($FileName)

        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application;
        $Selection = $Outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection                                                                       
        foreach ($Item in $Selection) {
            foreach ($Attachment in $Item.Attachments) {
                Write-Verbose $Attachment.FileName
                $Name = Join-Path -Path $textbox6.text-ChildPath $Attachment.FileName
                $Attachment.SaveAsFile($Name)


            }         
        }

    }
})
$Listbox1.Add_DragEnter({$_.Effect = [Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})
$Form12.Controls.Add($Listbox1) 

# Activate the form     

[void] $Form12.ShowDialog()
```

i had to change my form a little by adding an `Input Folder Button` & `Textbox6` to show the text of the folder that has been selected this is important as the Script above needs a directory to save the files to, please see code below.

```
###################################### Get Folder Using Folder Browser and output text into textbox 
$button4_Click = {

$folderBrowserDialog3=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$folderBrowserDialog3.ShowDialog()
$folderBrowserDialog3.SelectedPath
$textBox6.Text = $folderBrowserDialog3.SelectedPath
}

$button6_Click = {

$folderBrowserDialog1=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
$folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
$textBox2.Text = $folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
}

$button7_Click = {

$folderBrowserDialog2=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog()
$folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath
$textBox3.Text = $folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath
}
```

after i got that to work the thing that bugged me the most was i couldn't see the files in the `listbox` so i added a `button` to do exactly that please see code below

```
###################################### Shows Files In ListBox 1
    $button5_Click = {
    #$textbox8.Text = ""
    $listBox1.Items.Clear()
    $items = Get-ChildItem $textbox6.Text
    ForEach($item in $items){
    $listBox1.Items.Add($item.FullName)
       }
    }
```

as you can see i have added `$listbox1.Items.Clear()` this will enable you to keep clicking the show files button without it duplicating the path and file in the `listbox`

the final result of my `Form` has come out great please see my image layout below, if anyone needs help to get it working on your own `Form` please comment and i will do my best to help.

[image]